# Realm object predicate filter is invalid

Tags: swift, realm, predicate

I use predicate to filter the converstions of models. I got the wrong result with Realm filter (0 models though there should be one). After that, I did another check and she showed me that there is one model with these criteria. Please tell me what may be wrong here.

```
let checkConversations = Array(realm.objects(ChatConversationModel.self)).filter({ $0.lastMessage != nil && $0.toDelete == false })
    debugPrint("checkConversations", checkConversations.count) received one model (this is the right result).

    var conversations = Array(realm.objects(ChatConversationModel.self).filter("lastMessage != nil && toDelete == false"))

    debugPrint("conversations", conversations.count) I did not receive any models at all
```

Models:

```
class ChatConversationModel: Object, Mappable {

    /// oneToOne = friend
    enum ChatType {
        case oneToOne, group, nonFriend

        var index: Int {
            switch self {
            case .oneToOne:
                return 0
            case .group:
                return 1
            case .nonFriend:
                return 2
            }
        }
    }

    @objc dynamic var id = ""
    @objc dynamic var typeIndex = ChatType.oneToOne.index
    @objc dynamic var lastMessage: ChatMessageRealmModel?
    @objc dynamic var lastActivityTimeStamp = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var modelVersion = AppStaticSettings.versionNumber
    let createTimestamp = RealmOptional<Double>()

    // for group chat
    @objc dynamic var groupConversationOwnerID: String?

    /// for group chat equal card photos
    @objc dynamic var cardInfo: ChatConversationCardInfoModel?

    // Local
    @objc dynamic var toDelete = false

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    convenience required init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        if map.mappingType == .fromJSON {
            id <- map["id"]
            typeIndex <- map["typeIndex"]
            lastMessage <- map["lastMessage"]
            lastActivityTimeStamp <- map["lastActivityTimeStamp"]
            createTimestamp.value <- map["createTimestamp"]
            modelVersion <- map["modelVersion"]
            // for group chat
            cardInfo <- map["cardInfo"]
            groupConversationOwnerID <- map["groupConversationOwnerID"]
        } else {
            id >>> map["id"]
            typeIndex >>> map["typeIndex"]
            lastMessage >>> map["lastMessage"]
            lastActivityTimeStamp >>> map["lastActivityTimeStamp"]
            createTimestamp.value >>> map["createTimestamp"]
            modelVersion >>> map["modelVersion"]
            // for group chat
            cardInfo >>> map["cardInfo"]
            groupConversationOwnerID >>> map["groupConversationOwnerID"]
        }
    }

}
```

**Update:** When I receive actual conversations, I start comparing which already exists in the application. And looking for ids which are not in the result. Next, I find these irrelevant conversations and put toDelete = false, in order to "safely" delete inactive conversations. Since I listened to a podcast with one of Realm's developers, he advised not to delete an object that can be used. And since when receiving results with backend, any inactive conversation can be active again, so I chose this method. You can view the code for these functions.

```
private func syncNewConversations(_ conversations: [ChatConversationModel], userConversations: [ChatUserPersonalConversationModel], completion: ((_ error: Error?) -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let userConversationsIDs = userConversations.map { $0.id }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                    let realm = try Realm()
                    let userConversationPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT id IN %@", userConversationsIDs)
                    let notActualUserConversations = realm.objects(ChatUserPersonalConversationModel.self).filter(userConversationPredicate)

                    let filteredNotActualUserConversations = Array(notActualUserConversations.filter({ $0.lastActivityTimeStamp < $0.removedChatTimeStamp }))

                    let notActualConversationIDs = filteredNotActualUserConversations.map { $0.id }

                    let notActualConversationPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id IN %@", notActualConversationIDs)
                    let notActualConversations = realm.objects(ChatConversationModel.self).filter(notActualConversationPredicate)

                    let notActualMessagesPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "conversationID IN %@", notActualConversationIDs)
                    let notActualMessages = realm.objects(ChatMessageRealmModel.self).filter(notActualMessagesPredicate)

                    try realm.write {
                        realm.add(userConversations, update: true)
                        realm.add(conversations, update: true)
                        for notActualUserConversation in notActualUserConversations {
                            notActualUserConversation.toDelete = true
                        }
                        for notActualConversation in notActualConversations {
                            notActualConversation.toDelete = true
                        }
                        for notActualMessage in notActualMessages {
                            notActualMessage.toDelete = true
                        }
                        completion?(nil)
                    }
                } catch {
                    debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                    completion?(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share the declaration of your `ChatConversationModel` model class.

Comment: @bdash Ok, I did

Comment: I threw together [a complete test case based](https://gist.github.com/bdash/2903e8a0e799ba90fa7a45508af7e5f3) on your code snippets, filling in some of the missing classes, and was not able to reproduce the problem you're seeing. It'd be useful to determine what's different about my test case than what you're doing when you're seeing this problem.

Comment: @bdash I updated my post. I also want to report that I do not always get it done, that is, in most cases the result is correct. But sometimes an incorrect script happens during the same actions. Yesterday I did it 2 times in a row, and once in a few hours. If today this script is reproduced I will also write to you.

Comment: If you need more detailed help, please file a ticket at our GitHub issue tracker (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues) and put together a reproduction case. Otherwise, this is too specific for something like SO.

Comment: @AustinZ ok, thanks.